# How do I create contextual AUTO_INCREMENT in MySql?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I want to Create a Contextual increment, not sure of term I am using is correct.
here is my table

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `test` (
  `id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `abc` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `data` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`,`abc`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=4 ;
```

after this i did

```
INSERT INTO `test` (`abc`, `data`) VALUES
('hi', 'hello2'),
('hi2', 'hello2'),
('hi', 'hello2');
```

No in example given on page [MyISAM Notes](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/example-auto-increment.html) they have given an example, which is using enum, here I am not using enum, but they have not mentioned that it works for enum only. but the output i get is

```
1   hi  hello2
2   hi2     hello2
3   hi  hello2
```

but i wanted it this way

```
1   hi  hello2
1   hi2     hello2
3   hi  hello2
```

can anybody tell me what i am doing wrong here?

Comment: its there, [VMai](http://stackoverflow.com/users/3501730/vmai/) has solved the problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've got to swap the order of your indexes:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `test` (
    `id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `abc` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    `data` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`abc`, `id`)   -- id got to be second
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

I cite from the [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/example-auto-increment.html):

> For MyISAM tables, you can specify AUTO_INCREMENT on a **secondary**
>   column in a multiple-column index.

[Working example in this fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/12740/1)