# Auto increment unique column if value is taken

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel

I am trying to generate a unique slug for pages based on the title of the post the user enters so, say a title is "Once upon a time" this will translate into Slug->once-upon-a-time, however I want people to be able to have matching titles so if another person comes along with the same title I then want the slug to be Slug->once-upon-a-time2. How can this be done in laravel or just php. I essentially just want to try and save but if it fails then increment and then save again. Thanks for any info

Comment: You can implement this functionality in the database using a trigger.

Comment: You can implement this function in MySQL. You've got to use a MyISAM table, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23597482/how-do-i-create-contextual-auto-increment-in-mysql/ and MySQL will do what you want it to do automagically for you.

Comment: In reference to the above comments, what is this called ? and is it possible on innodb instead of MyISAM?

Comment: You can use the referenced solution by me only with MyISAM. Triggers you can use with every storage engine of MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't exactly an answer but why not separate by user and allow them to have identical post names? For example *'www.example.com/users/{user_id}/posts/once-upon-a-time'*, would avoid this issue completely and allow for checking out individual users writing.

Comment: I don't think it would avoid this issue completely. Why shouldn't the same user post the same slug twice?