# SQL Order String Primary Key

Tags: java, mysql, sql

I am wondering how to sort my SQL primary keys which is a `VARCHAR` composed of three parts. To generate a new key I need to find the largest number for the current year.

MC-#Year-#Number
**e.g.** MC-2014-1

Order in the database table:

```
MC-2013-5 
MC-2014-1
MC-2014-2
MC-2014-11
```

Something like

```
ORDER BY CAST(REPLACE(SUBSTRING(MC-2014-11,4),'_','') AS SIGNED)
```

However, the linked java programme could alo retrieve and sort the keys.

Comment: That is not easy to do in the face of concurrency / multiple transactions.
You'd need to do some locking.

Better to use a sequence or autoincrement column (you can reset it every year).

Comment: If you can, I'd suggest a composite primary key of 2 columns - year and number, then everything is much easier.

Comment: @user3703592 so you want to sort it based on the latest YEAR?

Comment: I like the idea of an autoincremented column + year column..

Comment: You find an example for that, what Thilo suggests, at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23597482/how-do-i-create-contextual-auto-increment-in-mysql/23597608#23597608

Comment: @wrecklez Yes I want the latest YEAR

Comment: @user3703592 can you give me some information about your DB? what is your tablename,fieldname

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The maximum number for the current year is simply

```
select max(cast(substring(code,9) as int))
from mytable
where code like concat('MC-', year(now()), '%');
```

But I agree with the others that you must think about locking, if you simply retrieve the maximum number this way to make an insert.

Answer (score 0):

if my understanding is correct, you just want to sort your records based on the latest year?
in that case you can do it using `MID,LEFT,RIGHT` in MySQL.. here's my example to sort it
but there's a limitation, the value of  that field is must be always on that format try this.
just change the `<tablename>` as your actual table and the `<fieldname>` for the field that contains that MC-2014-1

```
SELECT * FROM <tablename> ORDER BY mid(<fieldname>,4,4) DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

Given the answer from Thorsten Kettner here an example for MS SQL

```
select max(cast(substring(code,9, (LEN(code)-7)) as int))
from mytable
where code like concat('MC-', year(GETDATE()), '%');
```