# How to make auto-increment INSERT INTO statements?

Tags: mysql, sql, syntax, syntax-error, auto-increment

I really don't know how to explain this very well. This is the piece of code I'll be using as an example to help show what I need help with:

```
INSERT INTO _increment

(`user_id`, `group_id`, `alias`, `hash`, `function_id`, `value`, `notes`)

VALUES 

('262', NULL, NULL, 'john1', 'wewbsite.ca/', NULL, '0');
```

So this will make a new entry with the hash "john1". What I need, though, is for "john1" to become "john2" on the next entry, automatically. 
Like, the first time it runs, it's "john1", the second time, it's "john2", then "john3", and so on. How do I do this?

Thank you.

Comment: That's a difficult requirement and not entirely clear. What, if you're inserting a row with the value 'jane1'?

Comment: Is it possible at all to have an auto increment that has a name like "john1"? Can SQL add to the number after the name if the name consists of letters _and_ numbers?

Comment: With the MyISAM storage engine you could get that in a computed column, see my answer in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23597482/how-do-i-create-contextual-auto-increment-in-mysql. But I think you could gathering some experience first, before you implement features that are not very recommendable.

Comment: Hmm, that's also intriguing. Why is it not recommendable? Just wondering

Comment: It may be good looking at first glance but can harder to work with than a simple autoincrement value.

Answer (score 0):

I see two ways :

First : If you don't really need this column format, you should probably consider the fact to autoincrement a numeric column and concatenate the name (John) and this column to get this result (JohnX).

Second : But if you really need to get the exact name in this column because your boss want it like this, you should deal with `SELECT LAST(column_name) FROM table_name;` then parse it in your code to get the id and insert the result. But it's really not recommended.

Comment: Interesting. How would I go about concatenating the name? I know how to autoincrement a numeric column, so if I can get the concatenating of the name, we're golden.

Comment: I think what @Thomas means is that you store the name as it is (just "John" and allow duplicated values) and whenever you want data from the database (say, if you want to show it to your end user), show that concatenated value. Or create a `VIEW` out of this.

Comment: You do that with [CONCAT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) ... Be wise and consult a good tutorial and never forget to consult the manual.

Comment: Exact @TengyuLiu, I didn't know the CONCAT stuff. I think that it's not a big work to do that in upper layer of your architecture.