# For the same value it should be incremented by 1 and different it should be reset and gives result

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table like this and want to add a column so that for the same bpin it should    be increase by 1 and for different it should be reset and again start by 1.

```
BPIN     Name 
 101       A
 101       B
 101       C
 102       D
 102       E
 103       F
 103       G
 103       H
 103       I
 104       K
```

Need OutPut like:-

```
 BPIN     Name  Value
 101       A     1
 101       B     2
 101       C     3
 102       D     1
 102       E     2
 103       F     1
 103       G     2
 103       H     3
 103       I     4
 104       K     1
```

Comment: search for emulating `row number partition by` in MYSql

Comment: If this is an MyISAM table, you could get that automatically, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23597482/how-do-i-create-contextual-auto-increment-in-mysql/23597608#23597608

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using variables to do the count. The first sub query forces the order prior to the processing that adds the counter. The 2nd sub query initialises the variables.

```
SELECT BPIN, Name, @value:=IF(@bpin=BPIN, @value + 1, 1) AS value, @bpin:=BPIN
FROM 
(
    SELECT BPIN, Name
    FROM some_table
    ORDER BY BPIN, Name
) sub0
CROSS JOIN (SELECT @value:=0, @bpin:=0) sub1
```

SQL fiddle for it:-

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/79bfb/2

Answer (score 1):

Something like below will work

```
set @no:=0;
set @BPIN:='';
select BPIN,Name,@no:=case when @BPIN=BPIN then @no+1 else 1 end , @BPIN=BPIN 
from table;
```

Comment: Maybe you should add an `ORDER BY` clause

Answer (score 0):

You have to write a trigger with sequence.
But i think it's not necessary.

Add pk first. Each table should have one primary key.

Your table may looks like:

```
create table YourTable(
  id serial,
  bpin varchar(3),
  name varchar(1)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

...or slower but simpler...

```
SELECT x.*
     , COUNT(*) value 
  FROM my_table x 
  JOIN my_table y 
    ON y.bpin = x.bpin 
   AND y.name <= x.name 
 GROUP 
    BY x.bpin
     , x.name;
```